# Using different database for Members

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Is there a way to make my Umbraco website use a different database than Umbraco is using for the members of the website?
For example, when a user registers on my website, the data should be stored in a different database than the one Umbraco is using.

I'm using Umbraco 4.7.X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible because umbraco is using the asp.net membership provider internally for membership management.

You can setup you own membership database just the way you set up for any other asp.net base website.

Follow is the URL that show you the steps for the same.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers/how-to-integrate-aspnet-membership-control-with-umbraco